# How can I execute a command before login?

Tags: boot, 20.04, login, login-screen, execute-command

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

I want to execute the command `xdotool mousemove 960 540` to center my mouse pointer *before* login. I can do it just by adding the command to Startup Applications, but then it only runs after login. Any suggestions if it is possible?

Comment: What is your actual problem? Please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Search `crontab`

Comment: @pogodemon before login? do you mean on the GDM Login Screen, you want the mouse cursor in the center of the screen instead of default bottom right?

Comment: @UnKNOWn Yes, that's what I want

Comment: @pLumo Hello, it is my first time here. My problem is that my mouse cursor appears on bottom right of my screen instead of the center when it boots. I tried to correct it and found the command I posted here by Googling. It works when I enter my password and log in, but I need it to work prior to that as well.

Comment: Try this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450835/how-to-execute-command-before-user-login-on-linux

Comment: @pasmanpasmański I tried the GDM method but unfortunately I couldn't get it to work. I am supposed to put the path to the script I need before the "exit 0", right?